# How to use 2 Constructors?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I have the following class:

```
public class STElement
{
  public int _value;
  public STElement _next;
  public int _index;

  public STElement()
  {
    _value = 0;
    _next = null;
    _index = 0;
  }
}
```

In the runtime of the programm I want to create some objects like this:

```
_rootStack1 = new STElement();
_rootStack2 = new STElement();
_rootStack3 = new STElement();
```

But I only want **_rootStack1** to have the **_index = 0;**

So how can I do it, that only one of the three objects get _index?

Comment: Not sure if I follow, do you mean each successive `_rootStack#` would have an incrementing index? So `_rootStack1._index == 0`, `_rootStack2._index == 1`, and `_rootStack3._index == 2`?

Comment: `So how can I do it, that only one of the three objects get _index?` Do you want the others not to have `_index`?

Comment: You can't _ensure_ that you will only ever have a single object with `_index == 0`.

Comment: @phant0m correct, I only want _rootStack1 to have _index, _rs3 and _rs2, should not get them

Comment: keep in mind, all of them will have by default index=0 because it's the default value for an int. So the best solution is to have all the others have index != 0.

Comment: Or maybe you want to have the other instances to not have the index field at all? Then create a base class that doesn't have that field and derive it in a class that adds the field. That way you will have _rootStack1 = new STElementWithIndex(); and the rest will be instances of the base class. Is that what you want?

Comment: whats up with the downvotes? is my question to "noobish" for this site? ...

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler I think the downvotes are because your question is too ambiguous/confusing. I'm still not sure what you're asking for. Your class, as defined, has all instances have assigned to them _some_ `_index` value; all you've said is that the other two instances "should not get them" which _doesn't make sense_ (especially when they're all assigned `0` by default). We're trying to clarify what your thought process is and what you really want. Perhaps you should describe what end-task you're trying to achieve?

Comment: well I dont actually know how to explain further, I am a beginner :( maybe the complete thing i coded was wrong, well I am starting over now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a constructor that takes the value of an index and assigns it to the variable.

```
public STElement(int index)
{
  _value = 0;
  _next = null;
  _index = index;
}
```

This will not enforce that the object is the only one that has such a `0` index - this is not something an object can do directly.

Note on style - it is not good practice to have `public` fields. You should use properties to expose them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class STElement
{
  public int _value;
  public STElement _next;
  public int _index;

  public STElement()
  {
    _value = 0;
    _next = null;
    _index = 0;
  }
  public STElement(int index)
      : this()
  {
     _index = index;
  }
}


_rootStack1 = new STElement(1);
_rootStack2 = new STElement(2);
_rootStack3 = new STElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

STElement st1 = new STElement(1);

```
public class STElement
{
  public int _value;
  public STElement _next;
  public int _index;

  public STElement()
  {
    _value = 0;
    _next = null;
    _index = 0;
  }
  public STElement(int index)
  {
    _value = 0;
    _next = null;
    _index = index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass the needed index to the constructor?

You can make a constructor with a default parameter to not have to change the other calls made to it like so:

```
public STElement(int index = 0)
{
  _value = 0;
  _next = null;
  _index = index;
}
```

That way, all instantiations that don't pass an index will get the default value and for the others you can specify a certain index you want. Or you can do it the other way around, set the default value to be something different than 0 and only for the one you want, you can call the constructor with index = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can be overload constructors like methods.
Similar this:

```
 public STElement()
  {
    _value = 0;
    _next = null;
    _index = 0;
  }

 public STElement(int param1)
  {
    _value = param1;
    _next = null;
    _index = 0;
  }

 public STElement(int param1, int param2):this()
  {
    _value = param1;
    _next = null;
    _index = param2;
  }
```

...